# OSX-quality antialiasing on Awesome WM + Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, xorg, arch-linux, awesome-wm, anti-aliasing

I'm running Arch with Xorg and Awesome WM. The antialiasing rather sucks. How can I get OSX-quality antialiasing or something similar?

Comment: Note, your window manager only draws the borders around windows. It has nothing to do with the content displayed *in* the window.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. So it's Xorg that takes care of it, then?

Comment: No, Xorg is what actually puts stuff on the screen.  Your applications (e.g. Firefox) tell Xorg what to display *in* a window; the window manager tells Xorg what to display *around* the window.

Comment: Firefox is responsible for antialiasing the text displayed within the Firefox window.  Awesome WM is responsible for antialiasing the text in your windows' title bars.